# Can't figure out how to link my JavaScript into my html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I"m trying to follow a tutorial online on how to make a Todo list

I finished the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>To do list with html and javascript</title>
    <style>
    ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 400px;}
    li { border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #eee; padding: 5px 10px; color: #000; }
    li span { padding-left: 10px; cursor: default;}
    .checked { text-decoration: line-through; font-weight: bold; color: #c00;}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

<h1>To Do List</h1>
<p><iput type="text" id="inItemText"/>
    <ul id= "todolist">
    
</ul>


<script type= "text/javascript" src="todo.js"</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
// Each item should look like <li><input type = "checkbox"/> do tutorial</li>


function updateItemStatus (){

    var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_","");
    var itemText = document.getElementbyId("item_" + cb.Id);

    if (this.checked) {
        itemText.className = "checked";
}   else {
        itemText.style.fontWeight = "";
}

}


function removeItem(){
    var spanId = this.id.replace("item","");
    document.getElementById("li_" + spanId).style.display = "none";
}


function addNewItem(list, itemText){

    var date = new Date ();
    var id = "" + date.getHours() + date.getMinutes() + date.getSeconds() + date.getMilliseconds(); ;

    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    list.Item.id = "li_" + id;

    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id = "cb_" + id;
    checkBox.oneclick = updateItemStatus;


    var span = document.createelement("span");
    span.id = "item_" + id;
    span.innertext = itemText;
    span.ondblclick = removeItem;

    listItem.appendChild(checkbox);
    listItem.appendChild(span)


    list.appendChild(listItem);

}


var inItemText = document.getElementbyId("inItemText");
inItemText.focus();
inItemText.onkeyup = function (event) {

    // 13 means Enter

    if (event.which == 13) {
    var itemText = event.which;

    if (itemText == "" || itemText == " ") {
        return false;
    }

    addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist") itemText);

    inItemText.focus();
    inItemText.select();

};
```

I have both files saved in the save folder on my desktop. The JavaScript is still not coming up. Did I type something in wrong. I'm just trying how to link the JavaScript to my html sorry its my first time doing this.

Comment: You forgot a `>` in your script tags, anyway the script will not run until you call some of the functions. In your html there is nothing to call the script, but maybe you are aware of that and just posted a reduced version here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot `>`

```
<script type= "text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>
```

Comment: oh that did solve the problem. I did a simple alert just to check to see that its working. However; the file is still not working but thats because I think I wrote something wrong in my javascript or htlml. It just says todo and nothing is there. I think I need to re check the javascript on this

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type= "text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>
```

Thats all.. Since you forgot your `>` HTML thinks your tag is never over, until it sees the next `>`...